# Bootstrapping with glm model

Tags: r, loops, glm, sample, statistics-bootstrap

I have a negative binomial regression model where I predict Twitter messages' retweet count based on their use of certain word types (ME words, Moral words, and Emotional words):

```
M1 <- glm.nb(retweetCount ~ ME_words + Moral_words + Emo_words, data = Tweets)
```

I now want to sample with bootstrapping (for instance, samples of 1,000 with replacement from the dataframe's original 500,000 messages) from the large dataset, `Tweets`, to run iterations of the model and analyse the variance of the coefficients. What is the best approach to doing this? I am assuming I need to use the `boot` package, but I am a bit lost with where to start.

Ideally, I would like to create a for loop that can run a number of iterations, and then store the coefficients of each model iteration in a new dataframe. This would be extremely useful for future analyses.

---

Here is some reproducible data from the much much large dataframe `Tweets`:

```
>dput((head(Tweets, 100)))

structure(list(retweetCount = c(1388, 762, 748, 436, 342, 320, 
312, 295, 264, 251, 196, 190, 175, 167, 165, 163, 149, 148, 148, 
146, 133, 132, 126, 124, 122, 122, 121, 120, 118, 118, 114, 113, 
112, 110, 108, 107, 104, 101, 100, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 90, 90, 
89, 89, 87, 86, 84, 83, 83, 83, 82, 82, 82, 82, 78, 78, 78, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 74, 74, 73, 73, 72, 72, 71, 70, 70, 70, 70, 69, 69, 
69, 68, 68, 67, 65, 65, 65, 65, 63, 62, 62, 61, 61, 61, 61, 60, 
60, 59, 59, 59, 59, 58), ME_words = c(2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Moral_words = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0), Emo_words = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use the `boot` package, but for simple versions of the bootstrap it's almost simpler to roll your own.

### fit initial model

```
library(MASS)
M1 <- glm.nb(retweetCount ~ ME_words + Moral_words + 
                 Emo_words, data = Tweets)
```

### set up data structure for results

```
nboot <- 1000
bres <- matrix(NA,nrow=nboot,
                  ncol=length(coef(M1)),
                  dimnames=list(rep=seq(nboot),
                                coef=names(coef(M1))))
```

### bootstrap

```
set.seed(101)
bootsize <- 200
for (i in seq(nboot)) {
  bdat <- Tweets[sample(nrow(Tweets),size=bootsize,replace=TRUE),]
  bfit <- update(M1, data=bdat)  ## refit with new data
  bres[i,] <- coef(bfit)
}
```

### structure output

```
data.frame(mean_est=colMeans(bres),
      t(apply(bres,2,quantile,c(0.025,0.975))))
```